# How to use mysqli without implementing the prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

...........

$connection = mysqli_connect('......com', 'login', 'password', 

'dbname'); 
if (!$connection) { 
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connection Successful";



// creating a query 
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`,`firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, 

`password`) VALUES (NULL, $firstname, $lastname, $username,$email,$password);");
mysqli_close($connection);



// printing to the screen
echo "Welcome $lastname . You have successfully logged in!";

?>
```

The connection is OK, but the values do not get inserted. How can I improve my code? I do not understand why the values donot get inserted into the database. I have checked the variables, they are fine.

Comment: You can improve it by using prepared statements; or (at least) by remembering that string values have to be quoted in an SQL statement, and escaped in case they contain quotes themselves

Comment: Don't connect to a MySQL Database if you do not want to use prepared statements.. Simple

Comment: You need to escape the variables. Also, where the values come from, a $_REQUEST? is it throwing an error? By the way, you should consider prepared statement.

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand SO at all. Why not a single downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
"INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`,`firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`,

`password`) VALUES (NULL, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username','$email','$password');"

Comment: Make sure you run `mysqli_real_escape_string` on each of those variables first!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using prepared statements, you need to make sure that the SQL statement you create is complete and syntactically-correct, and that only the parts you want to be dynamic are dynamic (i.e. avoid SQL injection).

Rather than passing the string straight to `mysqli_query`, if you build it up in a variable first, you can echo it out to screen when debugging to spot obvious syntax errors.

In your case:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`,`firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, $firstname, $lastname, $username,$email,$password);";
die(htmlspecialchars($sql));
```

...will presumably show something like this...

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`,`firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, john, smith, jsmith1549348, john.smith@example.com);
```

...which is invalid SQL, because the strings have no quote-marks around them.

Since you also need to escape those values to avoid SQL injection, what you might end up with is more like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`,`firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $firstname) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $lastname) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($username) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($email) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($password) . "');";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

You'll probably want to add some whitespace in there rather than having it all on one ridiculously long line, and it's possible I made a typo, but hopefully you get the idea....

Answer (score 0):

Use wraper mysqli::query() for defence injection and using placeholder

```
<? class db{
private static $_instance;
private $db;
public function q(){return $this->db->query($this->make(func_get_args()));}
public function __get($property){return $this->db->$property;}
public function __call($method,$args){return call_user_func_array(array($this-   >db,$method),$args);}

public function qr(){
  $q = $this->make(func_get_args());
  echo $q;
  return $this->db->query($q);
}

public static function getInstance($conf){
  if(null===self::$_instance){
    self::$_instance = new self($conf);
  }
  return self::$_instance;
}

private function make($args){
  $tmpl =& $args[0];
  $tmpl = str_replace("%","%%",$tmpl);
  $tmpl = str_replace("?","%s",$tmpl);

  foreach($args as $i=>$v){
    if($i && !is_int($v)){
      $args[$i] = "'".$this->db->real_escape_string($v)."'";
    }
  }

  for($i=$c=count($args)-1; $i<$c+20; $i++)
    $args[$i+1] = "UNKNOWN_PLACEHOLDER_$i";
  return call_user_func_array("sprintf", $args);
}

private function __construct($conf){
  $this->db = new  mysqli($conf['mysql_host'],$conf['mysql_user'],$conf['mysql_pass'],$conf['mysql_db']);
  }

private function __clone(){
}
}

$mysql = db::getInstance([
'mysql_host' => '...',
'mysql_user' => '...',
'mysql_pass' => '...',
'mysql_db' => '...'
]);


$mysql->q('INSERT INTO `user` SET `first_name`=?,`last_name`=?',$f_name,$l_name);
```